# How can I predict a variable in the test data set, if the number of observations in the data set is smaller then in the training data set? Using R

Tags: r, linear-regression, prediction

Hi I am new to R an been stuck on this problem for a while:

I am using Bayes linear regression to make a model that predicts bear weight. The model looks like this:

```
bears.bayes<- stan_glm(WEIGHT ~ CHEST + NECK + HEADLEN +AGE, data=bears.train, seed=111)
```

As you can see the model is using a full data set, that has had the missing values omitted. The original data set had missing values only on the predicted (weight) variable. I am now trying to use the model to predict the NA's in the original data set.

What I tried is the following:

```
bears.test$predicted.weight <- predict(bears.bayes, bears.train)
```

```
bears.test$predicted.weight <- predict(bears.bayes, bears.test)
```

The error I get says that I can't predict as there are 44 observations in the full data set, but only 10 in the test data set.

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, predicted.weight, value = c(`52` = -1.77440983341086,  : 
  replacement has 44 rows, data has 10
```

**Can someone explain why that is? and if its possible to predict using unequal data sets?**

Comment: You should predict from the new dataset with `bears.test$predicted.weight <- predict(bears.bayes, bears.test) `

Comment: I just tried it out, and it just gives me the same error: